# Construct rectangles from tetraminoes

Tags: combinatorics

With five bilateral ("free") tetraminoes, you can not construct either a 4 × 5 rectangle or a 2 × 10 rectangle.

[image]

But from two sets of such tetraminoes it is possible to construct 4х10 and 5х8 rectangles. It is easy to prove that from an odd number of sets of tetraminoes one can not form rectangles.

[image]
[image]

The question is how to calculate the number of rectangles that can be constructed from a given even number of sets of five tetraminoes in the general case. For 4 sets, I can work it out. Variant 2х40 is impossible, and variants 4х20, 8х10 and 16х5 are obviously obtained from 4х10 and 5х8. More interesting is the case of 6 sets of 3x40 and 6x20.

Comment: It seems you want the number of possible dimensions of the rectangles, not the number of ways of using the set of tetraminos to form rectangles. i.e. if you have two ways to construct a rectangle of same dimension $w \times h$, it will be counted  once and only once, right? The second one seems a much harder problem.

Comment: @achillehui At first I would know can be construct 3x40 and 6x20 and what other rectangles can be construct.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** - This is supposed to be a comment but I need to show the picture.

---

For six sets of tetraminos, both the $3\times 40$ and $6 \times 20$ rectangles are constructible. Following is a construction for the $6 \times 20$ rectangle. If one cut it horizontally in the middle into two pieces, you can glue the pieces back to a construction for the $3 \times 40$ rectangle.

[image: Packing 30 tetraminos into a rectangle]

Comment: is it mean that any rectangles $n \times m$ are constructible if $nm=20X$, where $X$ number of sets tetramino and $n > m > 2$?

Comment: Since $4 \times 20$  and $6 \times 20$ are constructible, every even $X > 2$ can be written as non-negative combination of $4$ and $6$, so $X \times 20$ will be constructible. I don't think it can be generalized to all possible combination of $n,m$.